# Why does overfitting still happen after cross validation?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, classification, xgboost

It is a binary photo classification problem, I extracted the features using AlexNet. The measurement is log-loss. There are totally 25000 records in the training set, 12500 "1"s and 12500 "0"s, so the data set is balanced.

I trained a XGBoost model. After tuning the parameters using cross validation, the training log-loss is 0.078, the validation log-loss is 0.09. But when I make predictions using test set, the log-loss is 2.1. It seems that over-fitting is still pretty serious.

Why is that? Do I have to further tune the parameters or try another pre-trained model?

Comment: Just to make sure: did you shuffle your dataset before you split them into train/validate/test? you did not train with your validation data, right? double-check, sometimes we make mistakes.

Comment: what is "validation loss" here, and how is it related to **parameter tuning**? You mean - you run cross validation based evaluation of each hyperparameters, and the best ones got validation loss of 0.09, and then you used this model to test on the test set? If so, this is not how error estimation works, and test error has to be higher.

Comment: @lejlot Hi, could you explain more about how error estimation works?